# Cannot update Account via Salesforce API

Tags: php, api, salesforce

I'm trying to update a record via the SalesForce API (Enterprise WSDL).
The code works without any exception, and the result from Salesforce always says success. When I go to Salesforce, the Last Modified By indicates that my script did updated the record.

However, the field I wanted to update is not getting updated. I am sure it's something stupid. Could anyone help me to point it out, please?

```
$client = $builder->build();
    $results = $client->query("select Id, Issuer__c, Expiry_Date__c, Bond_Premium__c from Account where New_Group_Reference__c = '$groupRef' limit 1");
    $array = array();
    foreach ($results as $account) {
        //$account->Issuer__c = $info['issuer'];
        $account->Expiry_Date__c = $info['expiryDate'];
        //$account->Bond_Premium__c = $info['bondPremium'];
        $array[] = $account;
        var_dump($array);
        echo 'Account: '.$account->Id."\n";
    }
    $result = $client->update($array, 'Account');
    var_dump($result);
```

Result:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  object(Phpforce\SoapClient\Result\SObject)#1969 (3) {
    ["Id"]=>
    string(18) "0013000000NzSlxxxx"
    ["Expiry_Date__c"]=>
    string(10) "04/17/2016"
    ["Expiry_Date__cSpecified"]=>
    bool(true)
  }
}
Account: 0013000000NzSlxxxx
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  object(Phpforce\SoapClient\Result\SaveResult)#1973 (4) {
    ["id":protected]=>
    string(18) "0013000000NzSlxxxx"
    ["success":protected]=>
    bool(true)
    ["errors":protected]=>
    NULL
    ["param":protected]=>
    NULL
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ha! I realized why! It’s surely something stupid.
I forgot to regenerate the WSDL field after I added that field.

Comment: Same issue happens with me..Regenerate the WSDL, Update the Object getting success in API response But, Data is not updated.